# how can i replace two strings in javascript like this?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to assign src attribute to alt attribute with removing extension .png and removing src attribute.

```
string1='<img src="a.png"> hi '
```

to :

```
string2='<img alt="a"> hi '
```

how to do this?
what is code?

Comment: Is the string really this simple HTML fragment, or is it actually more complex? And what are you going to do with the string result? Is it ultimately going to become a DOM element?

Comment: it s not complex. i like to remove tags. result can be 'img:a hi'

Comment: Is it really `src=="a.png"`? (two `=`?)

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Also, note that `src` is a required attribute in both HTML4 and HTML5: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-1.html#attr-img-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string1.replace(/src=([^.]+).png/,"alt=$1");
```

However, there is probably a cleaner way to accomplish what you are trying to do using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the search-and-replace to the image element, you need to include img in the pattern:

```
string1.replace(/(<img [^>]*)src="([^.]+).png"/,'$1alt="$2"');
```

This has the added benefit of keeping your other attributes in tact.